# Why is my reference to AccountBalance returning a 0 amount?

Tags: c#, vba

I'm brand new to C# and am struggling with a program I am trying to create. I hope I can ask this question to the best of my ability. Per my assignment, we are creating a Windows Form in Visual Basic that creates an account. For the purpose of my question, I have an `Account` class, a Savings Account class (that is derived from the `Account` class), I have four forms, I have a `AccountForm` (that is the main form which displays the account number and the account amount using a string method). I have an estimate interest form, that needs to take the current `AccountBalance` from the account class (or savings account class, not sure which) and take user entered rate and term (which is collected from the `InterestForm`) to calculate an estimated interest. Right now, my `AccountBalance` on my `InterestForm` is returning 0 and I'm not sure why. Here is my code for the `InterestForm`.

```
namespace Assignment_6_third_attempt
{
    public partial class InterestForm : Form
    {

        private SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount();
        //private double accountBalance;


        public InterestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public InterestForm(double accountBalance)
        {
            accountBalance = savingsAccount.AccountBalance;
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void addInterestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateInterest();
            // this.Close();
        }

        public void CalculateInterest()
        {
            //A = P(1 + rt)
            double accountBalance = savingsAccount.AccountBalance;
            double interestRate = double.Parse(interestUpDown.Text);
            double term = double.Parse(termUpDown.Text);
            double estimateInterest = (accountBalance * (1 + (interestRate * term)));
            estimateTextBox.Text = estimateInterest.ToString("C");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have different `SavingsAccount` instances and are not updating the same one.  I don;t see anything in the code you post that would change `AccountBalance` from 0.

Comment: Yoiu need to post the code for `SavingsAccount`, as that is probably where the issue lies.   At a guess, you're probably not providing values for the properties in `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: @ Tim and D Stanley, true, I do not have a value provided under the SavingsAccount class (but I do under the Account class and the SavingsAccount class is derived from the Account class). When I retrieve it directly from the Account class it still returns that accountBalance is 0, despite under the Account class the accountBalance is assigned under an amount (based on the amount I've deposited). Is there a way to check which particular instance of accountBalance I am using? (besides hovering over it in Visual Studio).

Comment: Are you instantiating InterestForm passing a value as accountBalance?

Comment: @user3598756 I'm not sure what you mean.. Do you mean this--->        public InterestForm(double accountBalance)
        {
            accountBalance = savingsAccount.AccountBalance;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: @R.Schiff just because a class derives from another doesn't mean that every instance of that class included the same data as a parent instance.  If you have not covered instances in class but you're expected to share data between multiple forms then I suggest you get some guidance from your professor. There are ways to do it but you need to follow the curriculum you have been given so you do not jump ahead or fall behind the class.

Comment: @D Stanley, do you mean the protection level (private vs. public vs. protected), which I've fussed around with these a bit? As for a curriculum, there really isn't clear guidelines, we switched books halfway through the semester to Programming C# by O'Reilly. Up until now, most of our classes have been very straightforward. This is the first class using an actual programming language (as opposed to using Access v Excel). I'm open to any suggestions. If you have a recommended resource, I would appreciate that.

Comment: I mean that somewhere in your code a class must be instantiating InterestForm class. Is it doing by means of some "InterestForm myInterestForm = new InterestForm(10000)"?

Comment: @user3598756 Thank you. Would this code go in the Account class?

Comment: It should go where it already must be otherwise you wouldn't see any InterestForm show when you run your code. You can have VS help ypu searching all the occurrences of the InterestForm class: I'm not by any PC but you should place the cursor in any occurrence of InterestForm, right-clicking and choosing some "find all occurrences" or the likes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `InterestForm` constructor to:

```
public InterestForm(double accountBalance) : this()
{
   savingsAccount.AccountBalance = accountBalance; 
}
```

Comment: The designer *requires* a parameterless constructor that calls `InitializeComponent()` - it's probably better to chain the parameterized one and leave a parameterless constructor for the designer. Otherwise, this code breaks the designer.

Comment: @nikhilvartak Thank you. However, this is still returning a 0 amount.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have updated code to call default constructor

Comment: @R.Schiff Is this working for you? I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Comment: @nikhilvartak It's not. :( I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been at this for a few days and I've restarted a few times. Would it help to post the code from the SavingsAccount class and the Account class?